# Python String Replacement using only one line of code (replace "H" and "h" by "*")

Tags: python-3.x, string, str-replace

Python: In the string "Hello, how are you?" , how can I replace both "H" and "h" by "*" ? I'd like to do it in only one line of code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use re, for example:

```
import re
old_text="Hello, how are you?"
new_text = re.sub(r'h', '2', old_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print (new_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "Hello, how are you?"
s_replaced = re.sub('(H|h)', '*', s)
```

You can check the regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/MR4HWy/1).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this:

You can chain `.replace()` several times as it operates on and returns a string:

```py
>>> print('Hello, how are you?'.replace('H', '*').replace('h', '*'))
*ello, *ow are you?
```

Or use Regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[Hh]', '*', 'Hello, how are you?')
'*ello, *ow are you?'
```